# Cannot update Entries. Getting blank, unspecific error

Tags: channel-entries, error

I logged into a client EE site today to update some Entries, all of which are part of a custom channel Locations. I edited the info of one, saved it, and I got the error box on the top of the page. However, it's blank. Only 2 people have admin access to the site, myself and the client's IT guy. I cannot say with certainty what he may have done/changed. I haven't updated a location in roughly 2 months, but I have updated/added over 200 locations with no errors before now. I've tried editing other Location entries, and all error. I then tried editing non Location entries, and none of them error. I can add new ones, though. But since I cannot update existing entries, I cannot re-add old ones that need updating and close the old ones.

Error box seen here: http://screencast.com/t/CZuzo7H3Nd0

Comment: Are you trying to edit the existing entries as superadmin?

Comment: Yes. The account I use is the "master" account, so to speak. It has all privileges and permissions, and was the initial user account used when building the site.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?